# Cookie dialog popup flashes for a moment even when I've already accepted all cookies

Tags: bug, status-norepro, cookies

At the moment I frequently switch between SE websites, as I see different interesting questions.

Every time I switch to a new SE site I see a single frame flash of the cookie popup (I'm not sure if this is shown in non-GDPR countries) and then it disappears; as it knows I already have accepted cookies.

This is very distracting, and really annoys me.

I have even set the "reduced motion" preference, yet SE still shows this single flash.

This is a bug, as it should only show the popup if the user has never seen it, and hide it if the user has seen it. The current behaviour of flashing the popup if the user has seen it is too distracting.

Reproduced on Firefox under Ubuntu, and Chrome under Windows, when accessing SE from the Netherlands.

Comment: Happens to me too on the iPad. Not on FireFox on the laptop.

Comment: Thank you for reporting. This is part of a series of related bugs that the team is currently looking into.

Comment: @ferrybig is this still happening for you? We aren't able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Des It is still happening on Chrome on Windows. (did not have time to test on Ubuntu) It is a single frame showing the popup before going away. It seems like it only happens per site per session. So for example after 3dprinting stackexchange has shows 1 flash, I need to restart the browser to make it show the single flash again. Manually increasing the latency using chrome's dev tools still givesthe bug. Testing in private mode also has this behaviour (Why does the popup remember the accept all cookies in private mode, are there some sort of super cookies that take a single frame to load?)

Comment: @Ferrybig are you still seeing this today? Based on a few bug reports we adjusted some behaviors to better handle error corner cases and it'd be helpful to know if you're still seeing this. It's not something we could reproduce in the first place but _may_ be related to one of the fixes we pushed earlier in the week.

Comment: @NickCraver I experienced this bug a lot this week but have not encountered it today.

Comment: @NickCraver It is fixed for me